# Cross Thread Exception when trying to display Images from Camera Roll on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-8, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am building a Windows phone app using Xamarin in a portable class Library. I have got the Images from the Windows Phone Camera Roll and I am passing the List back to the PCL and assigning the Image to an ImageSource in my view.

**Windows Phone Get Images:**

```
foreach (var image in CameraRollPictures)
{
    Image img = new Image();
    img.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => image.GetImage());
    images.Add(img);
}           
return images;
```

**PCL method:**

```
    private RelayCommand _importPhoto;
    public RelayCommand ImportPhoto
    {
        get
        {
            return _importPhoto
                ?? (_importPhoto = new RelayCommand(
                                      () =>
                                      {
                                          IOperations op = DependencyService.Get<IOperations>();                                            
                                          Task<List<Image>> t = new Task<List<Image>>(() =>
                                          {
                                              return op.ImportPhoto();

                                          });
                                          t.ContinueWith((sender) =>
                                              {
                                                  PageOp.Navigate(new TaggingPage());
                                                  if (sender.Result.Count != 0)
                                                  {
                                                      try
                                                      {
                                                          App.Locator.TaggingPageVM.ImageSrc = sender.Result[0].Source;
                                                      }
                                                      catch (Exception ex)
                                                      {

                                                      }
                                                  }
                                              }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
                                          t.Start();
                                      }));
```

**View:**

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageSrc}"/>
```

**The Exception:**

> {System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Invalid cross-thread access.
>   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckThread()    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject..ctor(UInt32 nativeTypeIndex, IntPtr
>   constructDO)    at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage..ctor()
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinPhone.StreamImagesourceHandler.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinPhone.ImageRenderer.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.b__3(Object
>   state)}

**UPDATE**

If I load a picture from a resource then it works fine.

```
App.Locator.TaggingPageVM.ImageSrc = ImageSource.FromFile("50175950-tulips-microsofts.jpg");
```

It must be an error to do with the images created on the windows phone and passing those images back to my PCL

Comment: You have code after PageOp.Navigate, not sure that's a great idea.

Comment: The PageOP.Navigate basically calls `Navigation.PushAsync(Page)` and then the `App.Locator.TaggingPageVM` finds the VM associated with this page and sets the `ImageSrc` property

Comment: Have you tried wrapping that line in an invoker?

Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    App.Locator.TaggingPageVM.ImageSrc = sender.Result[0].Source;
});

Comment: I'm using Xamarin but I used Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { App.Locator.TaggingPageVM.ImageSrc = sender.Result[0].Source; }); Which is a similar method and worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Xamarin so:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { App.Locator.TaggingPageVM.ImageSrc = sender.Result[0].Source; });
```

Fixed the Cross-Thread error

Comment: I'm not completely sure of what causes this exception, but I'm thinking that it has something to do with the UI thread. I was getting this exception using the Xamarin Connectivity Plugin. Whenever the connection status changed I try to update a label saying that and if the app is doing some background work while the code reaches that instruction I get the exception. I surrounded the update label instruction with the "Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread..."  and haven't got the exception since then